# django python server- error: imageSaved() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am running a python-django server on my local computer

with django.urls i try to define a path to server that contains folder and file

**my code:**

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [

    path("", server.views.index, name="index"),
    path("imageSaved/<str:folder>/<str:picture>", server.views.imageSaved, name="imageSaved")
]
```

I try also:

```
 path("imageSaved/<path:path>", server.views.imageSaved, name="imageSaved")
```

And i got same error.

`imageSaved` **function from** `server.views`**:**

```
def imageSaved(request):
    res=request.__str__()
    return HttpResponse(res)
```

Because the path is a string I defined it that way:`<str:folder>/<str:picture>`

When i wrote a url:

```
http://localhost:5000/imageSaved/fff/ddd
```

I got error:

```
TypeError at /imageSaved/dd/dd
imageSaved() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder'
```

The Traceback is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/imageSaved/dd/dd

Django Version: 3.1rc1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'server']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django-3.1rc1-py3.8.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django-3.1rc1-py3.8.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /imageSaved/dd/dd
Exception Value: imageSaved() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder'
```

**Thanks!!**

Comment: This post is missing the contents of `server.views` and in particular the function `imageSaved`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I add server.views code to post

Comment: Here you go: `def imageSaved(request)` does not expect a `folder` argument. Check the following url and search for `def detail(`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very clear: you do not support the url arguments.

A view function transforms a request with optional URL parts into a response and it's signature therefore is:

```
def view_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

In your case:

```
def imageSaved(request, folder, picture):
    res=request.__str__()  # This isn't useful, but probably for debugging
    return HttpResponse(res)
```